# Signalr using Negotiate Authentication can send data from server to client for some users but not all

Tags: signalr

When using Negotiate Authentication for Signalr, all clients are able to connect. All clients are also able to call functions on the server with no issue. However, half of our users are not receiving data from the server. We have tried a hodgepodge of browsers and also the Signalr .Net Client for a WPF application.

Even some of the admin users with the highest privileges on the domain do not receive any data from the server, yet other admin users do. Signalr's longPolling just stays opening when data should be being sent.

The reason why I believe the issue lies with the Authentication is I switched authentication to Forms authentication and the server was able to talk to all clients with no issue. However, Forms authentication does not meet the business requirement.

I am using Signalr version 2.2.0 from NuGet.

Any information would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR worked fine. However the Negotiate Authentication User Identity Name must be the exact name as the name as the user I told SignalR to communicate with.

Long story short, our Active Directory admin uses capital letters sometimes and other times does not for user login names.